# Proving $a\mod{b}≤b-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$  and the remainder $r= a-b\cdot\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor$

> Prove: $a\mod{b}  ≤b-1$

$$b\cdot \lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor≤a<b\cdot\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor+b
 $$
Then
$$
a-b\cdot\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor=a\mod{b}<b
$$

However, the book reasoned that because $a\mod{b}$ is an integer, this, itself, implies

$$a\mod{b}≤b-1$$

How did that reasoning created that upper bound for $a\mod{b}$?

Comment: Note that the strict inequality $a < c$  implies $a \leq c - 1$ for integer $a$  and $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b-1$ is the largest integer that is less than $b$.

Hence the result.